# Java: one-liner to list Dirs in a directory?

Tags: java, directory

**One-Liner to list TXT-files.**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
...
files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
           public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
                }
           }
        );
```

[Source.](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0055.html)

**Is there an one-liner to list dirs in a dir?**

Comment: For very large values of "one"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static void main (String[] args)  throws Exception {
    File dir = new File("yourDir");

    FileFilter fileFilter = new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.isDirectory();
        }
    };

    File[] files  = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);

    for (File f : files)
        System.out.println( f.getName() );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This uses Commons IO, but really is the simplest way to list all the directory names.  It also has a way more powerful set of filters that you can use for other purposes:

```
String[] dirNames = new File("/Users/jonathan").list(DirectoryFileFilter.INSTANCE);
for (String dirName: dirNames) 
    System.out.println("Directory Name: " + dirName);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
...
files = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() { 
       public boolean accept(File pathname) { 
            return pathname.isDirectory();
       } 
    });
```

Note the use of [`listFiles(FileFilter)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FileFilter)) rather than [`listFiles(FilenameFilter)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FilenameFilter)).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import java.nio.file.Files and java.nio.file.Paths, which are available since Java 1.7. Then using streams, which were introduced in Java 1.8, you can do something like the following:

```
Files.list(Paths.get(".")).filter(x -> Files.isDirectory(x)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

This gets files in the current directory ".", lists them, and filters them so only directories are included, then iterates over the directories stream to print them out using a println method reference.

Actually you could use a method reference for the filter as well like so:

Files.list(Paths.get(".")).filter(Files::isDirectory).forEach(System.out::println);

Comment: As the first actual one-liner, this would really look good with an explanation of preconditions, assumptions, restrictions and maybe the core trick which allowed to get it into one line, even without a large value of "one".